# Create a table in big query with nested field

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I want to create a table with nested field,
i tried few methods to store it
1. sess_id - String agg_col(nested) as json

```
sess_id  agg_col
1001_0  "{""page_type"": 1, ""record_type"": 1, ""non_consectutive_home"": 0}"
1001_1  "{""page_type"": 1, ""record_type"": 1, ""non_consectutive_home"": 0}"
1003_0  "{""page_type"": 1, ""record_type"": 1, ""non_consectutive_home"": 0}"
```

Schema:

```
schema = [
          bigquery.SchemaField("session_id","STRING",mode="NULLABLE"),
          bigquery.SchemaField("unique_num_of_pages_","RECORD",mode="REPEATED",fields=[
                  bigquery.SchemaField("page_type", "INTEGER", mode="NULLABLE"),
                  bigquery.SchemaField("record_type", "INTEGER", mode="NULLABLE"),
                  bigquery.SchemaField("non_consectutive_home", "INTEGER", mode="NULLABLE")])]
```

This method create only two fields as

[image]

**Method 2:**

1. sess_id as string,
2. agg_col as dict

but i got an error as :

```
    dataset_ref = client.dataset('dataset')
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table('table_name')
    table = bigquery.Table(table_ref,schema=schema)
    table = client.load_table_from_dataframe(dff, table).result()
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-70-60a73e366976>", line 4, in <module>
        table = client.load_table_from_dataframe(dff, table).result()

      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\p37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\client.py", line 1546, in load_table_from_dataframe
        os.remove(tmppath)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp5dxv9a4o_job_509d5055.parquet'
```

Method 3 :
split the dict to 3 columns and using the same schema config but it still not work

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#bigquery_nested_repeated_schema-python, your schema is good but what about your data ? Having a String JSON is not the solution. You must have nested fields in your Dataset. Plus, you've put a `mode="REPEATED` so your JSON must be an array of JSON. Try rows like : `[{"page_type": 1, "record_type": 1, "non_consectutive_home": 0}]`.

Comment: @Rafaël - So your suggestion is list of dicts, i got the same error as described above(method 2)

Comment: It's indeed a dict, I didn't even realised that it was like your method 2. But I don't understand your error. Sounds more like a configuration issue than the wrong way to do it. I would look into it instead of finding a workaround. Can't help you with this exception though, sorry :/

Comment: @Rafaël - maybe it can't be done now, i found [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/8191)

Comment: Interesting to look at ! Thanks for sharing